# Magento 2.3 - What is the recommended practice for adding custom text in product page

Tags: magento2.3.4, product-page, text

I want to add custom text to the product page,

[image]

Here how can i achieve this task, which is the recommended way to do that: **Module (or) Events Observer (or) Preference**. What kind of workout safe for future version upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

You can add Custom Text on Product Page using below 2 ways:

- If Custom Text is product specific, you can create Product Attribute and add text value from backend. For Frontend, you can create new template and using layout block can show this Product Attribute value on desired location on product page.
- If its Same Text for all the products, you can create static block containing that custom text. Using layout block, you can place static block on desired location on product page.

This task you need to do in your theme so no module, observer and preference required.

Comment: Thanks for your knowledge sharing

Comment: Could you pls join, https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115081/magento-2-3-what-is-the-recommended-practice-for-adding-custom-text-in-product